# Concurrency in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, concurrency, jetty, apachebench

I have spring boot application with embedded jetty and its configurations are:
`jetty's minThread: 50`
`jetty's maxThread: 500`
`jetty's maxQueueSize: 25000` (I changed default queue to `LinkedBlockingQueue`)
I didn't change `acceptors` and `selectors` (since I dont believe on hard coding the value)

With above configuration, I am getting below jmeter test results:

1. Concurrent Users: 60

> summary = 183571 in 00:01:54 = 1611.9/s Avg:    36 Min:     3 Max: 
>   1062 Err:     0 (0.00%)

2. Concurrent Users: 75

> summary = 496619 in 00:05:00 = 1654.6/s Avg:    45 Min:     3 Max: 
>   1169 Err:     0 (0.00%)

If I increase concurrent users, I dont see any improvement. I want to increase concurrency. How to achieve this?

---

**===========================================================================
Updating on 29-March-2019**

I was spending more effort on improving business logic. Still no much improvement. Then I decided to develop one hello world spring-boot project.
i.e.,

> spring-boot (1.5.9)
>
> jetty 9.4.15
>
> rest controller which has get endpoint

code below:

```
@GetMapping
public String index() {
    return "Greetings from Spring Boot!";
}
```

Then I tried to benchmark using apachebench

75 concurrent users:

```
ab -t 120 -n 1000000 -c 75 http://10.93.243.87:9000/home/
Server Software:
Server Hostname:        10.93.243.87
Server Port:            9000

Document Path:          /home/
Document Length:        27 bytes

Concurrency Level:      75
Time taken for tests:   37.184 seconds
Complete requests:      1000000
Failed requests:        0
Write errors:           0
Total transferred:      143000000 bytes
HTML transferred:       27000000 bytes
Requests per second:    26893.28 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       2.789 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       0.037 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          3755.61 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    1  23.5      0    3006
Processing:     0    2   7.8      1     404
Waiting:        0    2   7.8      1     404
Total:          0    3  24.9      2    3007
```

100 concurrent users:

```
ab -t 120 -n 1000000 -c 100 http://10.93.243.87:9000/home/
Server Software:
Server Hostname:        10.93.243.87
Server Port:            9000

Document Path:          /home/
Document Length:        27 bytes

Concurrency Level:      100
Time taken for tests:   36.708 seconds
Complete requests:      1000000
Failed requests:        0
Write errors:           0
Total transferred:      143000000 bytes
HTML transferred:       27000000 bytes
Requests per second:    27241.77 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       3.671 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       0.037 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          3804.27 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    2  35.7      1    3007
Processing:     0    2   9.4      1     405
Waiting:        0    2   9.4      1     405
Total:          0    4  37.0      2    3009
```

500 concurrent users:

```
ab -t 120 -n 1000000 -c 500 http://10.93.243.87:9000/home/
Server Software:
Server Hostname:        10.93.243.87
Server Port:            9000

Document Path:          /home/
Document Length:        27 bytes

Concurrency Level:      500
Time taken for tests:   36.222 seconds
Complete requests:      1000000
Failed requests:        0
Write errors:           0
Total transferred:      143000000 bytes
HTML transferred:       27000000 bytes
Requests per second:    27607.83 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       18.111 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       0.036 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          3855.39 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0   14 126.2      1    7015
Processing:     0    4  22.3      1     811
Waiting:        0    3  22.3      1     810
Total:          0   18 129.2      2    7018
```

1000 concurrent users:

```
ab -t 120 -n 1000000 -c 1000 http://10.93.243.87:9000/home/
Server Software:
Server Hostname:        10.93.243.87
Server Port:            9000

Document Path:          /home/
Document Length:        27 bytes

Concurrency Level:      1000
Time taken for tests:   36.534 seconds
Complete requests:      1000000
Failed requests:        0
Write errors:           0
Total transferred:      143000000 bytes
HTML transferred:       27000000 bytes
Requests per second:    27372.09 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       36.534 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       0.037 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          3822.47 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0   30 190.8      1    7015
Processing:     0    6  31.4      2    1613
Waiting:        0    5  31.4      1    1613
Total:          0   36 195.5      2    7018
```

From above test run, I achieved ~27K per second with 75 users itself but it looks increasing the users also increasing the latency. Also, we can clearly note connect time is increasing.

I have requirement for my application to support 40k concurrent users (assume all are using own separate browsers) and request should be finished within 250 milliseconds.

Please help me on this

Comment: What do you mean by "increase concurrency"? And why do you expect better application performance using more concurrent users? As you have 500 accepting threads you probably won't see any jetty related performance changes with less than 500 concurrent users,

Comment: minimum 200 concurrent users may access our application and use web services in parallel and expected response time should be less than 200ms. I could see only ~80 to 100 threads are processing at a time irrespective of number concurrent users set in jmeter.

Comment: Maybe this is related to you jmeter setup?

Comment: I ran test using apachebench. and also added clear note. please take a look and help

Answer (score 1):

You can try increasing or decreasing the number of Jetty threads but the application performance will depend on the application logic. If your current bottleneck is the database query you will see hardly any improvements by tuning HTTP layer, especially when testing over local network.

Find the bottleneck in your application, attempt to improve it, and then measure again to confirm it's better. Repeat this three steps until achieving desired performance. Do not tune performance blindly, it's a waste of time.

Comment: Yes, now all our requests pointing to database. But I feel that db is already performing well on its limitation. I mean, our application is capable to do 6000 db operations per second. So we want to scale our application to process atleast 3000 requests/second. But dont know how to find correct path. I am new to this performance tuning.

Comment: Start by watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lJ8ydIuPFeU), performance is not easy to measure.

Comment: Could you please take a look on updated info and help